# python script argument misinterpreted in Hudson Execute Shell step

Tags: python, linux, shell, jenkins, hudson

When I run my python script in the shell terminal, it works

```
sudo myscript.py --version=22 --base=252 --hosts="{'hostA':[1],'hostB':[22]}"
```

But when I run in Hudson and Jenkins, using Execute Shell step, somehow, the string `--hosts="{'hostA':[1],'hostB':[22]}"` is interpreted as

```
sudo myscript.py --version=22 --base=252 '--hosts="{'hostA':[1],'hostB':[22]}"'
```

How do we overcome this so that our script would run in Jenkins and Hudson ?

Thank you.
Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're encountering a battle-of-the-quoted-strings type situation due to your use of quotes directly and the fact that `Jenkins` is shelling out from a generated temp shell script.

I find the best thing to do with `Jenkins` is to create a `bash` script that wraps the commands you want to run (and you can also have it do any other environment-related setup you may want to have it do, such as source a config `bash` script that sets up other env vars).

You can have it accept arguments that may vary from the command line, which can be passed to it from the `Jenkins` config. So any of the interpolation then happens within the script -- you're just passing strings. (In particular, in this case, you'll have the **hosts** arg be `"{'hostA':[1],'hostB':[22]}"`, which will be passed to the shell script, and then interpolated, with the double quotes re-included.

So, to that end, say you have a `jenkins_run.sh` script that runs a command like this:

```
myscript.py --version=$VERSION --base=$BASE --hosts="$HOSTS"
```

Where the variables are passed in as arguments and assigned prior to that (you could directly use `$0`, `$1` et al if you want.

I would also be cautious using `sudo` in conjunction with a `Jenkins` run, since that could end up prompting for I/O. I would instead recommend setting the permissions on the script such that the using under which `Jenkins` is running can simply execute the script.